Modeling legacy data in EF
I have a legacy .csv that my company uses to decode coded values in other tables. The .csv looks similar to this:



Header
Code
Literal
Description




header1
X
literal1X
description1X


header1
Y
literal1Y
description1Y


header2
A
literal2A
description2A



A combination of Header and Code essentially serves as the unique key for a record and there's 300+ different headers and each header has somewhere between 1 and 40 codes. Headers align with the header in other records so if I had tableA and tableA had header1 with a value of X, I'd find header1 with a Code of X in the CSV and know that the literal and description decode the value of the record. Each header represents a distinct clump of data and it's tempting to turn it into it's own table, create a navigation property and then map the codes as the key. But with 300+, that's kinda ridiculous.
Is there a better way to turn this into an entity in Entity Framework so that I could take a record that has header1 with a value of x and create a relationship that would allow me to get the remaining values?

I'd start with exactly what you have here: a model with four attributes Header, Code, Literal and Description. What makes you think that would not work?

Create a Code table and a junction table TableACode? Because I perceive this as a many-to-many relationship between TableA (Header) and Code.

@topsail a model with four attributes is perfectly fine here, the issue I have is knowing which one to look at during query time. When I'm querying a record in tableA with a value of x I don't know how to join it to the correct decoded record because I would have to have the header and the code. Each record would also need multiple of these.

@GertArnold it isn't a many to many unfortunately, I can see where you go that from though. I've updated my example.

OK, a Code table then, having a FK to TableA.
